# What are all the status effects and what do they mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've seen numerous different status effects pop out of enemies.  Some are somewhat self explanatory, but others are not.  A few of the effects I have seen:

- Snared
- Rooted
- Block
- Attack Slowed
- Frozen
- Immune

Some of these, such as Immune, are pretty obvious at first, but "Immunity" in Diablo 2 was simply very high resistance that could be reduced enough to break the immunity.  What do these status effects actually mean and what others are there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **Snared**: Your character is slowed down. The magnitude of the slow effect varies depending on what's doing the snaring.
- **Rooted**: Unable to move from your current position.
- **Attack Slowed**: You swing your weapons more slowly.
- **Chilled**: Snared + Attack Slowed
- **Frozen**: Mostly the same as stunned, but certain skills, like the Wizard's Frost Nova's Shatter Rune, cause frozen enemies to behave differently. Frozen enemies leave no corpse.
- **Immune**: Immune to whatever status effect you're trying to apply. This can be knockback, stun, snared, or any other status effect, depending on the individual in question. Bottom line - one or more of your status effects isn't "sticking", so to speak. Unlike Diablo II, no monster in Diablo III is supposed to be immune to a damage type (though they might have high resistances).
- **Knockback**: Physically moves the target away from the origin of the attack.
- **Stunned**: Rooted, *and* unable to attack.
- **Charmed**: Fight other monsters instead of the player
- **Feared**: Running in fear, unable to take action or control direction of movement.

Comment: how long each of those effects last?

Comment: @JimThio Depends entirely on what ability applied them (And what diminishing returns are present)

Comment: Oh ya, what about weapon with chance of freeze on hit. There is no mention on how long the freeze will last.

Comment: How much does "chilled" slow you?

Comment: @user86888 it depends on who or what is doing the chilling.

Answer (score 2):

[RavenDreamer's answer] was fairly complete, but I would add two additional status effects detailed in the [wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Status_effect).

> **Confusion** : disorients the target, making them unable to tell friend from foe.
>
> **Fire DoT** : A fire damage over time is a critical effect from a fire-based attack, and will cause damage over time. A target with a fire DoT is easy to see, as it will literally be on fire.

It's not clear from the wiki if these status effects can be generated by monsters or only by player characters, but it seemed most appropriate to add here.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that monsters can sometimes be completely immune to any attack. In that case you have to kill them indirectly:

shield: immunity is temporary, wait 5 seconds until it dies out.

invunrable minions: kill the leader, his minions will die with him.