# How does Snare effect work?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are some skills that cause a `Snare` effect to enemies. It seems they move slower for a certain time; do you know the exact percentage of movement reduction? Does Snare causes other effect other than slowing? And last one, are all Snare effect equals?

Comment: Can you link an example for such a skill from http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/ ? Because I've got a suspicion about the answer, but can't answer until I'm sure.

Comment: WitchDoctor's first secondary Grasp of the Dead

Comment: Monk's Tempest Rush should also snare.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are all the status effects and what do they mean?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63625/what-are-all-the-status-effects-and-what-do-they-mean)

Comment: @OrigamiRobot The other question seems very high level just wanting a description as opposed to this one asking for how to find the specifics on just this one type of effect. Not sure I would call them duplicates.

Comment: @James - Then Drake should ask for a more detailed answer on that question.  I don't see any reason to separate this information.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot The percentage of movement reduction and the difference between the different snares are details not provided by answer linked.

Comment: @Drake - See my above comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that a snare slows the targets down for a set amount of time.

While looking at the tool tip of a skill that has a snare effect press the control key. This will give you detailed information on the skill including but the duration of the snare and the reduction of movement speed that will be applied to the target.

While it is possible that your skill with snare on it will have other effects, it is not usually a direct result of the snare component of the skill itself.

Lastly, no, not all snare effects are equal and pretty much all of them are altered in some manner through runes. You can use the tool tips with the control key mentioned above or even just browse snare causing skills from the link @heishe posted in the comment to the question (Like here is a snare skill with extended duration for a demon hunter: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/demon-hunter#b!!b)