# What exacly does "reducts the duration of control impairing effects" do?

Tags: diablo-iii

Which are the control impairing effects this magic attribute is referring to?

Does this also reduce it's effectiveness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reduces the duration of effects such as being frozen, feared, or stunned; usually by Champion or Elite mobs, but also by certain bosses/their minions (Barbarian Shadow Clone, I'm looking at you).

It doesn't reduce the effectiveness of spells you cast.

Comment: For a full list of such status effects see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63625/what-are-all-the-status-effects-and-what-do-they-mean).