# What does "rooted" mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the status effects and what do they mean?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63625/what-are-all-the-status-effects-and-what-do-they-mean)

I've been blasting monsters with the Demon Hunter, and during a lot of the hits it shows "rooted" above the monsters head. What does that mean?

Comment: First definition - http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rooted

Answer (score 3):

Rooted basically means that the enemy cannot move.